# How come I am only getting red toggling error in my c++ code?

Tags: android-ndk

I am wondering where I went wrong, someone mind helping?

```cpp
#include "Resource.hpp"
#include "SoundManager.hpp"
#include "Sound.hpp"


SoundManager::SoundManager(android_app* pApplication)  :
    mApplication(pApplication),
    mEngineObj(NULL), mEngine(NULL), mOutputMixObj(NULL),
    mSoundQueues(), mCurrentQueue(0), mSounds(), mSoundCount(0) {
};

SoundManager::~SoundManager() {
    for (int32_t i=0, i<mSoundCount; ++i) {
        delete mSounds[i];
    }
    mSoundCount = 0;
}

void SoundManager::stop() {
    for (int32_t i=0; i< QUEUE_COUNT; ++i) {
        mSoundQueues[i].finalize();
    }
    //Destroys audio output and engine.
    for(int32_t i=0; i<mSoundCount; ++i){
        mSounds[i]->unload();
    }
}

registerSound():

Sound* SoundManager::registerSound(Resource& pResource) {
    for(int32_t i=0; i<mSoundCount; ++i){
        if(strcmp(pResource.getPath().mSounds->getPath() = 0) {
            return mSounds[i];
        }
    }
    Sound* sound = new Sound(mApplication, &pResource);
    mSounds[mSoundCount++] = sound;
    return sound;
}

void SoundManager::playSound(Sound* pSound) {
    int32_t currentQueue = ++mCurrentQueue;
    SoundQueue& soundQueue = mSoundQueues[currentQueue%QUEUE_COUNT];
    soundQueue.playSound(pSound);
}
```

error occurs right after registerSound() multiple instances where spots are barely shaded red underneath, saying I need symbols, or something is expected, but I am just not quite getting it, any help would be great thanks. the errors occur...
-at the star symbol for sound*

-the & symbol after Resource

-after the ) and before the { after pResource

-at for

-at the ; after mSoundcount

- the ++i

-again between the ) and {

-at if

-at the . after pResource and the . before mSounds and the -> and at 0

- return and the [ and ]

-the two } } shortly after

-after mSounds at the [ and ++] and the =

- return again

and at }

Comment: exact errors are at all locations defined

Comment: maybe the compiler is reading it wrong? there shouldn't be errors

Comment: it says that a ( is expected at the * after sound, everything clears once i remove it but i cannot remove it, it is required in the .hpp file

Comment: Is the `registerSound():` intended to be a label?

Comment: That `registerSound():` makes no sense. Unless it's supposed to be a comment and you just forgot the leading `//` (?)